# Can I set an endDate to n/a in Schema.org SaleEvent?

Tags: date, schema.org, json-ld

I am trying to find the correct way of setting the `endDate` in a Schema.org `SaleEvent`.

Right now this is what I am doing, but I'm wondering if this is the correct way? I'm actually still waiting for Google to show these results, so I can't test if it works yet.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "SaleEvent",
    "name": "<?=$obj->title;?>",
    "url": "<?=$fun_domain.'/'.$fun_shop_page.'/'.$shop_slug;?>",
    "startDate": "<?=date("Y-m-d",$obj->ctime);?>",
    <?if(!empty($obj->expiredate)){echo'"endDate": "'.date("Y-m-d",$obj->expiredate).'",';}?>
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "<?=$shop_name;?>",
        "url": "<?=$shop_home_url;?>",
        "address": "<?=$shop_name;?>"
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to provide an end date, omit it completely rather than setting an invalid value. This seems to be what your code is doing, but the title of your question seems to indicate otherwise. Your code as it is now would appear to be correct.

Comment: Alright thanks, just wanted to know if there was another "correct" way of doing it.

Comment: Doesn't really seem to work with the ones that doesnt have an expire date, google just started to show the sale events in the search results today, but not the ones with no expire date

Comment: @Anders Google's rich snippets are a completely separate topic to the raw schema.org. I suggest you have a look at Google's documentation for the specific rich snippets you want to show. This schema.org is compliant with the specification, but might not be what Google wants. That's up to Google.